# creating certificate for windows azure deployment with PHP Zend - Failed to download RDP file for instance

Tags: php, azure, cloud-hosting

i m working with win Azure, deployment 
i not enable to take remote login of the instance.

here is the error.

```
    Failed to download RDP file for instance 
servicecall_webrole_IN_0 in cloud service testingservicecall.
```

details:

```
The supplied cscfg file can not be parsed. 
Got exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword.
```

config file

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="MIIBnQYJKoZIhv..." />
```

any worked with php with win azure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have uploaded your remote desktop certificate into your hosted service before deployment and RDP password in cscfg file encrypted using same certificate..

from error it looks like, password is stored in plain text in cscfg? You will have to encrypt the password in cscfg using csencrypt tool available with azure sdk.

Comment: i have created the certificate with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432987.aspx , but how to encrypt the password ? which need to be pasted in the cscfg config file.

Comment: There is a csentrypt tool along with azure sdk. You can run this tool from your machine to generate encrypted password. Paste it in cscfg. See thi link for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh404001.aspx